# How to automate calculations in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, automation, calculation

I'm currently struggling to find good information on how to calculate differences, percentages etc. using several columns and rows in a Pandas dataframe - and how to show the output in a nice table using Python.

Short example of what I'm going for:

[image: Here is an example for the kind of table I am going for:]

I'm working with NBA data and have gathered a bunch of match statistics for home and away teams during the 2019/20 season (the season finishes later this month). The first row shows the Free Throw percentage and "Regular" means regular matches **with** audience members and "Bubble" denotes the matches **without** audience members.

A short view of my Pandas dataframe:

[image: A snippet of my Pandas dataframe.2]

How do I automate the calculations using Python code? Feel free to give me examples!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a good  pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: sounds like you'll want to look at the `.groupby()` in pandas to calculate based on specific subsets. as anky stated, you'll want to provide some code here (at the very least a sample of the data set and what you're expected outcome to be).